# How to get human-readable event type from QEvent?

Tags: qt, qevent, qgadget

I want to debug event handling code and would like to convert `QEvent::Type` enum's value to a human-readable string. `QEvent` has a `Q_GADGET` macro, so presumably there's a way of pulling that off?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Recent versions of Qt do the right thing when outputting events to the debug stream, so the below isn't neccessary.** If you get an error similar to `warning C4273: 'operator <<' : inconsistent dll linkage`, it means that your version of Qt already supports this without need for the code below.

The `Q_GADGET` macro adds a `QMetaObject staticMetaObject` member to the class. The static metaobject's definition is generated by moc, and it - in the case of `QEvent` - contains the enumeration information.

Below is an example of how to leverage that to give a more reasonable `QDebug` output of events.

```cpp
#include <QEvent>
#include <QMetaEnum>
#include <QDebug>   

/// Gives human-readable event type information.
QDebug operator<<(QDebug str, const QEvent * ev) {
   static int eventEnumIndex = QEvent::staticMetaObject
         .indexOfEnumerator("Type");
   str << "QEvent";
   if (ev) {
      QString name = QEvent::staticMetaObject
            .enumerator(eventEnumIndex).valueToKey(ev->type());
      if (!name.isEmpty()) str << name; else str << ev->type();
   } else {
      str << (void*)ev;
   }
   return str.maybeSpace();
}
```

Use example:

```
void MyObject::event(QEvent* ev) {
  qDebug() << "handling an event" << ev;
}
```

Comment: _Recent versions of Qt do the right thing when outputting events to the debug stream, so the below isn't neccessary._

Could you please more specific what version please?

Comment: Given the date the answer was edited, it would be at least the version available back then, and that is 5.8. Possibly earlier versions too.

Answer (score 7):

Q_GADGET and Q_ENUM can be combined to get the following template:

```
template<typename EnumType>
QString ToString(const EnumType& enumValue)
{
    const char* enumName = qt_getEnumName(enumValue);
    const QMetaObject* metaObject = qt_getEnumMetaObject(enumValue);
    if (metaObject)
    {
        const int enumIndex = metaObject->indexOfEnumerator(enumName);
        return QString("%1::%2::%3").arg(metaObject->className(), enumName, metaObject->enumerator(enumIndex).valueToKey(enumValue));
    }

    return QString("%1::%2").arg(enumName).arg(static_cast<int>(enumValue));
}
```

Example:

```
void MyObject::event(QEvent* ev) 
{
    qDebug() << ToString(ev->type());
}
```